# Quick Settings Toggle in Android N

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I'm trying to add a quick settings toggle to my app in Android N. The quick tile shows up, but it doesn't do anything when clicked. I can see the visible feedback when touched, so I know that it is recognizing the click, but it doesn't do anything when clicked.

Here's my service code:

```
public class QuickSettingTileService extends TileService {

    public QuickSettingTileService()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID)
    {
        //some setup code is here

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick()
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Quick Setting Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toggle code is here
    }
}
```

My manifest has the code almost directly copied from the documentation. Only slight modifications have been made:

```
<service
    android:name=".QuickSettingTileService"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/quick_toggle_off"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The service is started upon opening the app:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, QuickSettingTileService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: Try logging to LogCat, rather than using a `Toast`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove these lines from your QuickSettingTileService class

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID)
{
    //some setup code is here
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

There is no need to override onBind() or onStartCommand() on a TileService.

Also, you don't need to explicitly start this service. The permission and intent-filter in the manifest will make sure Android OS will start your service when your tile is added to the Notification bar.

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks! I was originally getting an error without overriding onBind, but I think I was mistakenly extending Service at the time instead of TileService.

Comment: I'm glad that worked out. Please remember to mark as answer so this can help other people.